# Как сделать 301 редирект с раздела на предыдущий раздел (для сервера Apache)?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, редирект, http-status-code-301

Как сделать 301 редирект с https://www.moisait.ru/razdel/clear/ на https://www.moisait.ru/razdel/ ? При этом очень много разделов где добавляется clear, например могут быть и такие:

```
https://www.moisait.ru/razdel2/clear/
https://www.moisait.ru/razdel3/clear/
https://www.moisait.ru/razdel4/clear/
```

С них тоже нужно сделать редирект с clear на предыдущую папку. Подскажите как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно обработать разные подразделы, где добавляется "clear", вам нужно будет использовать регулярные выражения.

Вот пример того, как вы можете сделать это в `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/clear/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Это правило означает следующее:

1. `RewriteEngine On` включает модуль перезаписи URL.
2. `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/clear/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]` описывает правило перезаписи:

   1. `^([^/]+)/clear/$` - это регулярное выражение, которое означает "любая последовательность символов, не содержащая `/`, за которой следует `/clear/` в конце строки".
   2. `/$1/` - это то, на что будет произведена перезапись. `$1` представляет собой содержимое первой скобки в регулярном выражении (в данном случае, всё до `/clear/`).
   3. `[R=301,L]` - это флаги перезаписи. R=301 означает 301 переадресацию (постоянное перемещение), а `L` означает, что это последнее правило, которое следует применить.

Это правило сработает для запросов типа `https://www.moisait.ru/razdel/clear/` и перенаправит их на `https://www.moisait.ru/razdel/`.

Comment: не сработало =(